# Lock portrait and landscape in ios

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7, ios6, orientation

how can i lock landscape in ios., i was tried many method but not worked, Can any one share latest code for lock landscape.

```
-(void) portraitLock {
    BSEAppDelegate* appDelegate = [UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
    appDelegate.screenIsPortraitOnly = true;
}

- (NSUInteger) application:(UIApplication *)application supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(UIWindow *)window
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}

+(BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    return NO;
}

-(BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {

    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);

}
```

Comment: Why do you return `UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait` when you want a landscape? As far as I know, `shouldAutorotate` needs to be an instance method `(-)`, not a class method `(+)`.

Comment: i was return No and Yes., that is also not working.., what i will do ?Could you tell ?

Comment: Hi Bhavesh. is not to lock hole Application. Is single Page

Comment: That code i was try but not working.,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft || interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight);
}
```

As of IOS6 shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation was depreciated in place of willRotateToInterfaceOrientation or didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation

You should also change the views orientation to Landscape in the Attributes Inspector.

If your entire app is to be displayed in Landscape you can also add UISupportedInterfaceOptions to your apps info.plist and specify Landscape.

Answer (score 0):

Check above Image

[image: Check Image]

check only Portrait mode.,,,,